# Product distribution function of two independent (mixture of discreet and continuous) random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider two random variables say X and Y, the first being the standard normal, while the other is the radamecher taking a value of 1 or -1 each with probability 0.5. what is the probability density function of Z=XY?

Comment: We have $\Pr(XY\le w)=\frac{1}{2}\Pr(Z\le w)+\frac{1}{2}\Pr(Z\ge -w)=\frac{1}{2}(\Pr(Z\le w)+\Pr(Z\lt w))=\Pr(Z\lt w)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The standard normal distribution is symmetric about the origin, meaning the density function $f(x)$ satisfies $f(x) = f(-x)$.

Comment: what if not symmetric about the origin?